# discord.py - Post error to on_command_error

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

I have a error handler for my cog, *cog_command_error*, but I want, that if the error can't by handled in the local error handler, it will be send to the general error handler *on_command_error*.
How can I post the error?

My local error handler (shorted):

```
    # mod.py
    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if ctx.command.name == 'purge':
            if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
                await ctx.send(embed=Embed(color=Color.orange(), description="The number must be a integrer number!"))
        if ctx.command.name == "kick" or "ban":
            if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
                await ctx.send(embed=Embed(color=Color.orange(), description="You must mention the member you will ban!"))
        else:
            # Post the error to on_command_error
```

The general error handler (shorted):

```
    # error.py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        # check for local error handler
        if hasattr(ctx.command, 'on_error'):
            return
        # check for cog error handler
        if ctx.cog:
            cog = ctx.cog
            if cog._get_overridden_method(cog.cog_command_error) is not None:
                return
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("You have not the permission to execute this command!")
            return
        else:
            print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know if this is a copying mistake but you're missing a few `await`s in the `cog_command_error` method, `ctx.send` should be awaited.

Comment: It was missing, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely call the global error handler manually with additional args:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error, passed = False)
   if passed:
       #error is sent from cog handler by us
   else:
       #error is from an error event
```

```py
async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
   #other stuff
   else:
       await on_command_error(self, ctx, error, True)
```

Note: This will work for now, but it is definitely advisable to use a single error handler globally. i.e Use `on_command_error` or `cog_command_error`. Not both.